# .copy() does not create a deep copy

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame called `df`.
This data frame is composed of 2 columns named `Summary` and `KeyWords_in_Array`.

Each row in the column `df["KeyWords_in_Array"]` is composed of an array.

I want to create a new column called `KeyWords_in_Array_wo_insurance` such that is equal to `df["KeyWords_in_Array"]` but deleting the element "INSURANCE" if present in the array.

My code is the following:

```
df["KeyWords_in_Array_wo_insurance"] = df["KeyWords_in_Array"].copy(deep=True)
df["KeyWords_in_Array_wo_insurance"] = df["KeyWords_in_Array"].apply(lambda k: k.remove("INSURANCE"))
```

**HOWEVER**

The new column `df["KeyWords_in_Array_wo_insurance"]`  is filled with `None` and the old column `df["KeyWords_in_Array"]` does not contain anymore the element "INSURANCE" in the array.

I do not understand what I am doing wrong since I did a deep copy of the `df["KeyWords_in_Array"]` and thus the new columns should be totally not connected.

Comment: provide sample data if you can, it would help a lot

Comment: I added some more information, hope it helps

Comment: it does. People are confused because you don't specify that your data is a list of lists, hence the result of None. Also, never post sample data as images, people can't use it

Comment: Many thanks. I am not sure why you say that it is a list of lists? The list are composed of single elements (strings). Unless you are referring to the strings as a specific type of list.

Comment: you're right, is a series of lists, should've been more precise. The column KeyWords in Array is a series of lists, look at the solution provided by DeepSpace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You created a `.copy` of `df["KeyWords_in_Array"]` and stored it as `df["KeyWords_in_Array_wo_insurance"]` but called `.apply` on `df["KeyWords_in_Array"]`, so in reality the second line of code should be

```
df["KeyWords_in_Array_wo_insurance"] = df["KeyWords_in_Array_wo_insurance"].apply(lambda k: k.remove("INSURANCE"))
```

Another problem is that `list.remove` is in-place and returns `None`, so you can't use `.apply` the way you did.

**However**, this would still *not* work.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'KeyWords_in_Array': [['a', 'b', 'c', 'INSURANCE']]})
df["KeyWords_in_Array_wo_insurance"] = df["KeyWords_in_Array"].copy(deep=True)

def remove_insurance(k):
    k.remove('INSURANCE')
    return k

df["KeyWords_in_Array_wo_insurance"] = df["KeyWords_in_Array_wo_insurance"].apply(remove_insurance)
print(df)
#    KeyWords_in_Array KeyWords_in_Array_wo_insurance
#  0         [a, b, c]                      [a, b, c]
```

Why?

`Series.copy`'s docstring has some insight:

> Notes
>           -----
>           When `deep=True`, data is copied but actual Python objects
>           will not be copied recursively, only the reference to the object.
>           This is in contrast to `copy.deepcopy` in the Standard Library,
>           which recursively copies object data (see examples below).
>
> While `Index` objects are copied when `deep=True`, the underlying
>           numpy array is not copied for performance reasons. Since `Index` is
>           immutable, the underlying data can be safely shared and a copy
>           is not needed.

**Solution**

Manually copy `df["KeyWords_in_Array"]` to `df["KeyWords_in_Array_wo_insurance"]` **and** use a better function with `.apply`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'KeyWords_in_Array': [['a', 'b', 'c', 'INSURANCE']]})
df["KeyWords_in_Array_wo_insurance"] = [list(data) for data in df["KeyWords_in_Array"]]

def remove_insurance(k):
    k.remove('INSURANCE')
    return k

df["KeyWords_in_Array_wo_insurance"] = df["KeyWords_in_Array_wo_insurance"].apply(remove_insurance)
print(df)
#       KeyWords_in_Array KeyWords_in_Array_wo_insurance
# 0  [a, b, c, INSURANCE]                      [a, b, c]
```